# ReST API security

Tags: android, rest, security

I am creating an Android App that will communicate with ReST API . And i want to know how do I provide security to the APIs

Here is my sample API method

```
@GET
    @Path("/count")
    public String totalUserCount(){
        return "100";
    }
```

and here is my call to api from android

```
StringRequest stringRequesttoNearby = new StringRequest(
                        Request.Method.GET, 
                        url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String responseString) {
                             //response
                            }
                        }, 
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            }
                        })
                {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();                  
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                //add request to queue
                Singleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(stringRequesttoNearby);
```

So I want to know how I can add security to this API call

Comment: https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way/ and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: https://medium.com/javarevisited/how-to-secure-the-rest-apis-b682e21821a1
this is really nice article if we use spring

Answer (score 0):

You could use Oauth1.0a, Oauth2 check out the link

Follow link [Secure Api](https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way/)